# Two XML elements with the same name and XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm writing a program that loads XML files and uses the data to create objects in Unity. Creating a XmlSerializer object results in the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The XML element named 'compatibility' from namespace '' 
is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another
XML name or namespace for the element.
```

This would indicate that Unity has a `[XmlElement(ElementName = "compatibility")]` or similar attribute on some unseen/internal project code somewhere. As a side note, I've written a simple console app that does not have this issue, using the exact same code (less one or two Unity specific functions).

I'm unable to edit the XML I'm reading in (as it's generated by another program), which does not specify a namespace.

I've tried setting the Namespace property of some or all of my elements in my serialization classes, but I always end up with a "unexpected <eagle xmlns=' at 1, 4" or similar error. I've also tried generating the file via XSD tool, same "unexpected" error as above. Finally I tried creating a XmlNamespaceManager object, creating and pushing a new namespace, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

What can I do to solve this issue?

XML snippet (note, did not include the entire file as it's around 500 lines long. XML is well-formed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE eagle SYSTEM "eagle.dtd">
<eagle version="8.4.3">
<drawing>
<settings>
<setting alwaysvectorfont="no"/>
<setting verticaltext="up"/>
</settings>
<grid distance="50" unitdist="mil" unit="mil" style="lines" multiple="1" display="no" altdistance="5" altunitdist="mil" altunit="mil"/>
<layers>
<layer number="1" name="Top" color="4" fill="1" visible="yes" active="yes"/>
<layer number="2" name="Route2" color="1" fill="3" visible="no" active="no"/>
<layer number="3" name="Route3" color="4" fill="3" visible="no" active="no"/>
```

Class XML is being serialized into:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "eagle")]
    public partial class EagleXML
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "compatibility", Order = 0)]
        public CompatibilityNote CompatibilityNote1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "drawing", Order = 1)]
        public Drawing Drawing { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "compatibility", Order = 2)]
        public CompatibilityNote CompatibilityNote2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public partial class CompatibilityNote
    {

    }

    [Serializable()]
    public partial class Drawing
    {

    }
}
```

Class doing the deserialization:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public class PCBScript : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public const string brdPath = @"ProperPathToXmlFile";

        void Start()
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

            XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlEagleUrlResolver();

            settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationFailed);
            settings.XmlResolver = resolver;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EagleXML));

            EagleXML loadedFile = (EagleXML)serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(brdPath, settings));

            Console.WriteLine("Loaded xml");
        }

        private void ValidationFailed(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to validate");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have two different properties with the xml Element name 1) [XmlElement(ElementName = "compatibility", Order = 0)] 2) [XmlElement(ElementName = "compatibility", Order = 2)]  The Element name is the tag name in the xml file and you can't map the same xml element to two c# properties simultaneously.

Comment: You can't map one element to two properties, but you can map two elements to two properties. The order indicates (as specified by the 3rd party DTD) that the eagle element has a compatibility element, then a drawing element, followed by another compatibility element.